# How to use eyefinity

Tags: multiple-monitors, eyefinity

I keep hearing the term eyefinity.  Can someone explain how to achieve eyefinity?  I have 3-4 monitors, what else is needed for this?  Just a video card or 2 or is there more to it?

Comment: Jason, were you able to find something that worked for you?

Answer (score 7):

Eyefinity allows you to drive up to 6 monitors using a single GPU.  You can either run applications which span multiple monitors, or use each monitor separately.  Note that you need a dongle if you want to drive more than two monitors from a single Eyefinity-compatible video card.  AMD has a [list of supported dongles](http://support.amd.com/us/eyefinity/Pages/eyefinity-dongles.aspx).

Requirements (quoted from [AMD's website](http://sites.amd.com/us/underground/products/eyefinity/whatiseyefinity/Pages/what-is-eyefinity.aspx)):

- ATI Radeon 5400 or higher
- Driver version 8.66 (ATI Catalyst ™ 9.10) or above is required to support ATI Eyefinity Technology and to enable a third display you require one panel with a DisplayPort connector.
- ATI Eyefinity Technology works with games that support non-standard aspect ratios which is required for panning across three displays.
- TV Tuner required, sold separately.
- Linux support scheduled to be enabled via a future ATI Catalyst™ driver release.

EDIT: Also, be sure to check out the article on Tom's Hardware, [AMD's Eyefinity Technology Explained](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/amd-eyefinity-6-displayport,2596.html).

Comment: Dongles are only necessary if your monitors don't already support DisplayPort, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you need 4 monitors and graphic card does not support 4 monitors, but has Display Port - you need to buy MST (Multi Stream Transport) Hub and connect it to display port.

Like this: http://www.club-3d.com/index.php/products/reader.en/product/mst-hub-1-3.html or this: http://www.accellcables.com/K088B-003B.html