# Impossible to use a 3rd monitor in Windows 7 with HD6950

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I bought a new monitor 24'' to add to my 2 other monitors (24'' and 26''). They're all 1920*1200, and are all recognized individually, and 2 at the same time can always work (through HDMI et DVI1).
My graphic card is an ASUS HD6950 2GB and it has 2 mini Display ports as well as 1 HDMI and 2 DVI. I tried to connect my 3rd monitor through DVI then through the mini display with an adaptor, and in both cases it's recognized but when I try to get to activate the 3rd screen, here's what I get:

- In Windows resolution config [image: Windows error]
- In Catalyst Control Center [image: Catalyst error]

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Look into Eyefinity that should allow you to support 3 monitors.  http://superuser.com/questions/122885/how-to-use-eyefinity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that card, you can't use both DVI ports *and* the HDMI at the same time.

Also, if you want to use mDP to a DVI monitor, then you need an ["active" adapter](http://ca.startech.com/AV/Displayport-Converters/Mini-DisplayPort-to-DVI-Dual-Link-Active-Adapter%E2%80%93USB-Powered~MDP2DVID).

From the manual of a version of your card, here's a chart of acceptable display configurations (second one from the bottom is the 3x DVI monitor configuration your aiming for):

[image]

More info here: [Active vs. Passive DisplayPort adapters *the truth*](http://www.overclock.net/t/721931/active-vs-passive-displayport-adapters-the-truth)

Including this tid-bit:

> Eyefinity requires an ACTIVE adapter to enable a third monitor on HD
>   5000 cards. Passive will NOT work, except for the first two monitors
>   on the eyefinity 5 and eyefinity 6 cards. For the other three/four
>   monitors, active is still required.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot, I wouldn't have understood this chart alone anyway :) I've just ordered an active adaptor (and found on Amazon  plenty of comments from people with the same problem).