# ATI Radeon Triple Monitor Setup

Tags: windows-7, amd-radeon, multiple-monitors

I have a Dell XPS 8300, and its got an ATI Radeon HD6450 installed.  When running Ubuntu 12.04 the triple monitors work flawlessly.  I can change the default, turn them on/off etc ...

The problem is Windows 7.  It is behaving much like in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/515244/impossible-to-use-a-3rd-monitor-in-windows-7-with-hd6950).  I know the card supports three, as it WORKS PERFECTLY in the linux portion of my dual boot.  Windows can "see" all three, but will only allow two.  Is this a WIndows 7 / ATI compatibility issue, or is Windows 7 just stupid (rhetorical)?  Had I not had a dual boot Linux box, I might have read the above thread and thought "damn, it just won't work".  But I use three monitors every day on this card, so I know it works....  Just not with Windows.

**Note**: I am using HDMI, DVI and VGA. Three displays work perfectly in Linux (Ubuntu 12.04), so I know the card supports concurrent connections to ports I am using.

Comment: What ports are you using? You can't use two DVI ports at the same time.

Comment: I have a similar card and on Windows I needed to use the mini display port and an active adapter. Not sure about Linux, sorry.